# Compile templates client side with Emberjs 1.10 without node?

Tags: ember.js

We have been using Ember for our MVC app through version 1.9. Now, with 1.10 it appears as though we need node to precompile templates somehow on the client side before they are viewed in the application, is that correct?

Unfortunately, we work in a very restricted environment where node and npm are "coming", but we don't have them yet. We've simply been including the handlebars.js file with ember to make our app work at runtime. So my real question -  is there a way for me to continue using the newest versions of handlebars (or HTMLbars) and ember within my app without the need for node?

Please let me know if I'm missing something. I read the blog post (http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/02/05/compiling-templates-in-1-10-0.html) and lots of other discussion on this topic and I can't seem to understand this enough to move forward. Thanks in advance for any clarification you provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am going to make a lot of assumptions based on my assuredly poor understanding of your question. Please forgive me if I am telling you things that are already known to you.

The `ember.js` script can't read a `.hbs` file natively. That goes the same if you are using `<script type="text/x-handlebars">` to define your templates. Same deal: It must be translated into pure Javascript before Ember actually understands it.

This conversion can either happen on the client side (in browser), or it can be done ahead of time by you. If it is done on the client side, there are more dependencies that Ember requires than if that doesn't have to happen. This has always been true.

The only difference is that now, instead of that dependency being called `handlebars.js`, it is called `ember-template-compiler.js`.

People talking about Node, Grunt, or Ember-CLI are talking about tools that are used to ease the development process. Often these tools will crunch down all the Ember dependencies into one file that is already purely Javascript and doesn't need to reference any `.hbs` files.

Assuming you develop off of the starter kit available on the front page of emberjs.org, you can still keep upgrading your app as you have in the past and it should all work fine. Just download the new stater kit and remember to change your `<script>` tag in your `index.html` file to reference `ember-template-compiler.js` instead of `handlebars.js`.

To illustrate something similar to this:

```
<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/handlebars.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/ember.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

Becomes something like this:

```
<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/ember-template-compiler.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/ember.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

I hope I understood your question enough to help.

Comment: Thank you. You were right about my setup and sorry for the poor description (should have provided more setup information). The missing piece was that I could not find the Ember compiler, because I don't usually download the starter kit, I download from the builds page and the compiler is not available there. When you try to find it on the web, you can find nothing but node builds and those all require you to be compiling with node as you would expect. Thanks for your answer, you totally cleared things up for me!